# Invalid URL error when using suggestions in ESRI locator service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

I have created and published a locator service with suggestions turned on. I enabled suggestions when building the locator files and after publishing them as a service. The service published correctly and geocoding from the rest endpoint works fine. E.G.

```
http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BLDGADDRESS/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Street=&Single+Line+Input=88+quale&category=&outFields=*&f=html
```

this works fine

However using the suggest option give an invalid URL error e.g.

```
http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BLDGADDRESS/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=555+night&f=html
```

gives a 404 bad URL error. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was caused by bad source data. The Feature Class used to create the locator had a number of points that had invalid or missing geometry, the points could not be zoomed to in ArcMap. Once I deleted these points and rebuilt the locator the suggestions worked.